# How to exclude specified files from SVN reintegrate branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, svn-reintegrate

I have 2 branches what I'm reintegrating

In both branches I have same CFG files what I dont want to be reconciled.
Wanted keep them versioned but not reconciled.

Do you know any way how to exclude specified files from this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the working copy (being merged) has no local modifications before the merge, can't you just revert those configuration files after the reintegration is done, but before you commit?

Another option is if the changes to the configuration file(s) are committed separately from your other changes, then you could exclude those revisions from the merge. So instead of the branch re-integration option in TortoiseSVN, you could merge a [range of revisions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html#tsvn-dug-merge-range). More work for you though.

Comment: Good point. This might work. Do you know any parameter excluding files from reintegration or such stuff ?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. I'll update my answer with another more complex solution you might like to consider.